# getent passwd doesn't work; CentOS 7 and SSSD LDAP authentication

Tags: authentication, ldap, centos-7

I installed CentOS 7 on a brand new server. All my servers get end user authentication through LDAPS on various system as RHEL5, Debian, and Solaris. I noticed there is a new layer on CentOS 7 which is SSS above NSS and PAM. Anyway, I try to replicate the same type of connection as the other server.

The command `ldapsearch -x` is binding in LDAP, but not in LDAPS.

While digging the problem, I tried to do a connection in LDAP squeezing the SSS layer putting these lines in my `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

```
passwd:     files ldap #sss 
shadow:     files ldap #sss 
group:      files ldap #sss
```

And I added this line in the `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`

```
cache_credentials = False
```

And I restarted ssd.

```
systemctl restart sssd
```

I check with the command `authconfig --test` and everything seems ok: (http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/1LZ2)

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if this is the proper solution but noticed in the [SSSD FAQ](https://docs.pagure.org/sssd.sssd/users/faq.html#when-should-i-enable-enumeration-in-sssd-or-why-is-enumeration-disabled-by-default) this point:

> **When should I enable enumeration in SSSD? or Why is enumeration disabled by default?**
>
> "Enumeration" is SSSD's term for "reading in and displaying all the
> values of a particular map (users, groups, etc.)". We disable this by
> default in the SSSD in order to minimize the load on the servers with
> which SSSD must communicate. In most operation, listing the complete
> set of users or groups will never be necessary. Applications will
> generally request information about specific users or groups.
>
> Enumerating all entries has a negative impact in load on the server
> and performance on the client (as we have to save all of the complex
> relationships between users and the groups to which they belong in the
> local cache). So because of this, we ship with enumerations disabled
> (the same behavior as the Samba project's winbind).
>
> You should only enable enumerations (and the resultant performance
> issues) if you have applications or scripts in your environment that
> absolutely must be able to retrieve the complete lists. In these
> cases, enumeration can be enabled by setting
>
> ```
>    [domain/<domainname>]
>    enumerate = true
>    ...
> ```
>
> in your sssd.conf file.

This enabled the ability of `getent passwd` to display all the accounts that were available via SSSD. Be warned that this can be a performance drag.